# flash current working directory after creating a new file

Tags: ruby

For example, my working directory called "abc"(empty dir), in here, i start up a ruby script that will be create a new directory and file under the current directory, like this "abc/a/a.file". When it need to read this file at the same process of this ruby script(never close),  it can't knows it(new file).  So, i need to tell the current ruby process to flash itself known directory of current working.

I can't got any answer in google, thanks for someone who can help this problem.
I just let the current process to know and reread the new file that be created itself.

Answer (score 1):

For the current directory the process is using:

```
Dir.pwd
```

For the directory that the script is running from:

```
File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

For the directory that a file you've created is in:

```
f = File.new( "blah.rb", "w" )
# => #<File:blah.rb>
File.dirname f
# => "."
```

I hope that answers your question.

---

If you know the directory:

```
dir_name = "/my/amazing/project/"

# this returns an array of file names (no dot files) - but just the names.
files = Dir.new(dir_name).entries.reject{|f| f.start_with? "." }

# this will give you an array with each entry being the full path to each file.
files = Dir.new(dir_name).entries.reject{|f| f.start_with? "." }.map{|f| File.expand_path File.join( dir_name, f ) }
```

Try the code above in irb, just replace `dir_name` with a directory path, even `"."`.

Comment: But, the file is created by other program that is invoked by ruby, the process of ruby cannot know that file would be created after starting, so, how to tell the ruby process somewhere have many files be created.

Comment: What arguments does the ruby script pass to the other process? i.e. the directory path, the dir name, the file path, the file name... ?

Comment: The ruby script pass a directory name to other process, then many files will be created by that process in the directory given.

Comment: See my edit above for how to get the files when you've got the directory path.

Comment: Thank you for paying more attention to this question, i will deal with this question later, i am trying to figure out why would occur this problem now.